# Python not looking in file for string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, io

I am trying to get Python 3.5 to look in a file for a variable. I have tried to convert`username` to `str(username)` but to no avail. Here is the offending piece of code:

```
if str(username) in fi.read():
         hasAccount = True
         print("found username")
      else:
         hasAccount = False
         print("notfound")
```

Any ideas? This one has me absolutely baffled.
Thanks

P.S. I have already used `with open("usernames.txt", "a+")as fi:` earlier in the code.

P.P.P.S. People were asking for an MCVE, so I hope this counts:

```
with open("usernames.txt", "a+")as fi:#opens usernames file as "fi" and closes once finished
with open("userinfos.txt", "a+") as f:#opens userinfos file as "f" and closes once finished
   with open("quizzes.txt", "a+") as fil:
      listofinfos = ["surname", "yeargroup"]#list with information apart from name and age

      if True:#will always run
         name = input("Enter your name:")
         age = input("Enter your age:")
         username = name[:3]+age#shortens name variable to first 3 letters and concatenates with age

      if str(username) in fi.read():
         hasAccount = True
         print("found username")
      else:
         hasAccount = False
         print("notfound")
```

Comment: are you calling `fi.read()` several times in your code? do you have more than 1 condition? you can do `fi.read()` only once without rewinding.

Comment: P.P.S. I have also searched for solutions, but obviously didn't find anything, or I wouldn't be asking!

Comment: a [mcve] would be good at this point.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Yes I am, how does that affect it?

Comment: Post the minimal file to reproduce your problem (only whatever the username is?), such that if we ran the script above we can see the failure.

Comment: A better practice is to save `fi.read()` as a variable because you can only do this once per file open. If you have multiple `read()` to `fi`, the rest will return nothing.

Comment: @SupaSped my crystal ball was right. `fi.read()` reads the file. Next call reads nothing because you're at the end of the file

Comment: Is this OK?
`with open("usernames.txt", "a+")as fi:
    with open("userinfos.txt", "a+") as f:
       with open("quizzes.txt", "a+") as fil:
          listofinfos = ["surname", "yeargroup"]

          if True:
             name = input("Enter your name:")
             age = input("Enter your age:")
             username = name[:3]+age

          if str(username) in fi.read():
             hasAccount = True
             print("found username")
          else:
             hasAccount = False
             print("notfound")

Comment: Thanks for all the help, and so quickly! @Jean-FrançoisFabre Should I make a variable with `fi.read` and call that repeatedly, instead of what I did?

Comment: yeah, that's exactly what you should do.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way I can credit an answer via comment here?